# Hidden div and stay appeared after hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div which is hidden and i want on hover to appear and stay like that.

```css
#content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#content:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  TEXT
</div>
```

Comment: In my opinion and experience, hover is meant to simply display the some detail of the item while the cursor is over top of it. To actually change the item, such as to display a hidden div, some other event has to take place to apply the change permanently. Say a "Click" event

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery [hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```js
$('#content').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('show');
  }
);
```

```css
#content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#content.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  TEXT
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
  });
});
```

```css
#div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
  TEXT
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jQuery instead of CSS as in the snippet below, with `addClass`. But you have to add `!important` to the `opacity: 1`value as shown to override the initial setting.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content').mouseenter(function() {
    $("#content").addClass("seeme");
  });
});
```

```css
#content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.seeme {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  TEXT
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for any JavaScript here; simply set the `transition-delay` property of the element to a ridiculously high time that will never (normally) be met and then reset it to `0s` on `:hover`.

```
#content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    transition: opacity 1s 36000s; /*10 hours!*/
    opacity: 0;
}
#content:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay:0s;
}
```